# Accessing data frames or matrices through a variable in R

Tags: r

Say I have a series of data frames or matrices x1, x2, x3..., etc, e.g.

```
> x1
         [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7] [,8]   [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
V1 -0.5824644 -0.17 -0.23  0.26 -0.13 -0.25 -0.34 0.82  -1.93 -0.31 -0.40 -3.02
V2 -1.7916906 -0.16 -0.24  0.01 -0.12 -0.29 -0.38 0.68  -2.48 -0.46 -0.60 -3.62
V3  1.9726578 -0.87 -0.91  2.17 -0.79 -2.52 -1.23 5.35 -19.62  0.40  0.27 -7.86
V4 -0.5824644 -0.14 -0.19 -0.36 -0.17 -0.23 -0.32 0.40  -0.14 -0.34 -0.45 -2.85
V5 -1.7916906 -0.15 -0.20 -0.46 -0.22 -0.27 -0.34 0.93  -0.28 -0.63 -0.62 -3.65
V6  1.9726578 -0.37 -0.46 -0.46 -0.26 -1.14 -0.58 2.81  -1.05  0.39 -0.34 -5.48

> x2
         [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7] [,8]   [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
V1 -0.5824644 -0.19 -0.24  0.19 -0.27 -0.27 -0.40 0.76  -2.51 -0.45 -0.50 -3.80
V2 -1.7916906 -0.14 -0.21  0.06 -0.15 -0.24 -0.33 0.61  -2.06 -0.31 -0.43 -2.92
V3  1.9726578 -0.81 -0.88  2.38 -0.27 -2.12 -1.11 4.56 -14.94  1.75  0.19 -6.27
V4 -0.5824644 -0.13 -0.18 -0.21 -0.18 -0.25 -0.29 0.20  -0.30 -0.46 -0.42 -2.71
V5 -1.7916906 -0.12 -0.20 -0.37 -0.21 -0.23 -0.36 0.52  -0.28 -0.68 -0.63 -3.88
V6  1.9726578 -0.33 -0.39 -0.40 -0.28 -0.95 -0.52 2.25  -1.27  0.16 -0.23 -5.29

> x3
         [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7] [,8]   [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
V1 -0.5824644 -0.14 -0.22 -0.02 -0.22 -0.27 -0.35 0.56  -2.06 -0.39 -0.45 -3.32
V2 -1.7916906 -0.15 -0.20  0.08 -0.22 -0.24 -0.33 0.45  -2.19 -0.38 -0.41 -2.98
V3  1.9726578 -0.53 -0.58  1.39 -0.69 -1.23 -0.81 2.90 -11.02  0.96 -0.09 -5.30
V4 -0.5824644 -0.14 -0.19 -0.38 -0.17 -0.24 -0.31 0.43  -0.22 -0.49 -0.52 -2.96
V5 -1.7916906 -0.13 -0.22 -0.35 -0.25 -0.32 -0.43 1.01  -0.36 -0.55 -0.59 -3.71
V6  1.9726578 -0.25 -0.33 -0.33 -0.22 -0.90 -0.54 2.42   0.08 -1.19 -0.25 -4.04
```

I need to access and manipulate different data frames/matrices, depending on the value of an integer variable i - 1, 2, 3..., etc. I found many similar questions on the web, but all the solutions seem to involve `assign`, with the data frames/matrices being assigned by hard coding. This doesn't work for me because I read in my data from text files. I also tried something like

> `master_df = list(x1,x2,x3)`

but I can't manipulate the individual data frames by row or column.
`master_df[1]` returns the first data frame, but things like

```
master_df[1][,1]
```

don't work.

In Perl or Python, I would concatenate two variables to get the name of a third. In R, this doesn't seem to work; I get a string literal instead. I.e., in Perl or Python I would concatenate 'x' and 1 to get x1, which I can manipulate as needed, but in R I end up with "x1" that I can't do anything with. This seemed like a trivial problem that I can't solve for a while now, despite the extensive googling. Am I missing something or what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

To index a list, use double square brackets (`[[]]`). To index the `data.frame` using single square brackets (`[]`).

For example: `master_df[[1]][, 1]` will return all rows of the first column of the first element in the list `master_df`

Comment: Ah, thanks, I knew there is bound to be something like this in R, but I couldn't work out the syntax. But is there an option of concatenating a string literal ("x") and an integer variable to manipulate the data frames?

Comment: @Stefan Don’t do that, it’s not needed here and it makes your problem more complex than necessary.

Comment: Hmmm, I was trying to do it because (I think) this is the easier and more straightforward option. The master_df route creates an additional (and large) variable, plus the original data frames remain unchanged, which (in this specific case) is not what I want.